# Facebook Graph API get author of liked books

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to put all books info of a user in a database. To do that, I need the author of the liked books.

The problem is that the data that came after the "me/books" request is the one below. It doesn`t provide enough information.

**How could I extract the author information of a book?**

```
"data":[  
      {  
         "category":"Book",
         "name":"The Great Gatsby",
         "created_time":"2014-12-12T13:29:12+0000",
         "id":"109577692393195"
      },
      {  
         "category":"Book",
         "name":"To Kill a Mockingbird",
         "created_time":"2014-12-12T13:24:29+0000",
         "id":"430808383725764"
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make an API call to the id and check out "written_by" in the result:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=109577692393195&version=v2.2

Comment: Auch, that was easy. I missed this solution. Thanks.
@luschn